# Combination of MapReduce and Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Can we use a `combination` of `Hive` and `MapReduce`

Say: I am having a csv file. I need to find the `mean` of a column and replace the null data with the mean(`replace null with mean`).

so whether we can write a `hive query` in driver (to find the mean) then write a mapreduce block to replace the null with mean.

Which is better way

1. writing only mapreduce code or
2. Use a combination of hive and mapreduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the other answer that can be solved using (**only hive**)

say your csv input is like this:

```
firstname,secondname,score,group
```

vijay,kumar,123,cse

satish,babu,,it

kumar,nagendra,200,eie

anil,babu,,it

then apply query like this(i ran it worked) :

```
hive> from students s join (select avg(score)as avg from students) a
> select s.firstname,
> case
> when s.score="" or s.score=NULL then  cast(avg AS string)
> else s.score
> end as new_score ;
```

### Total MapReduce jobs = 2

output:

OK

```
firstname       new_score
```

vijay   123

satish  161.5

kumar   200

anil    161.5

Time taken: 67.059 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)

Comment: thanks sree :) , by the way use csvserde to make your job easy with csv input

Comment: can we do aggregations also(like max ,min,sum,mean,sd of each column) using Hive.For that which is better(Hive/mapReduce)

Comment: ya we can do all aggregations using hive. but to acheive all these things in single hive query results in complexity of query as well as performance. In such case (to achive all aggregations in one with good latency) use mapreduce-refer mapreduce design patterns > summerization patterns.

Answer (score 0):

According to my view,

Its better to write a mapreduce code only.(use job1 to find mean, then map only job2 to replace which is easy). combination of hive with MR will be a bit messy(reason for this is you are going to write both in one code, have to ship it to cluster nodes a jar, we cant say where these tasks will run, i mean where hive command execution point ll be).

hope this helps. Thanks :)